# opening a local web page with a jEditorPane

Tags: java

Sirs,

I am developing a GUI in Java with Netbeans.

For the purposes of prototyping, I am needing to open an HTML document (that is located on my hard drive) into a jEditorPane.  The code that I currently have is this:

```
HtmlPane.setPage(new URL("C:\\Users\\blah\\Desktop\\example1\\example1\\PracticeHTML.html"));
```

This throws a `java.net.MalformedURLException`.

When I try:

```
HtmlPane.setPage(new URL("https://www.example.com"));
```

The example.com page opens as one would expect in my HtmlPane.

Obviously, anything beginning with `C:\\Users . . .` isn't a *bona fide* URL in that the computer never has to get on the world wide web to get to the html document, but I fail to see why this throws an exception.

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `new File("C:\\Users\\blah\\Desktop\\example1\\example1\\PracticeHTML.html").toURI().toURL()`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that a file path in itself is not a url. To specify a local file as a url you need to do something like this:

```
file:///[path]
```

The full syntax is

```
file://[host]/[path]
```

... but `host` is assumed to be `localhost` if missing.

Comment: @the_photon Great! If the solution worked you should accept the answer by clicking the check mark over there <---.